# How to draw a circle in a square in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following `Canvas` class for drawing color in a given pixel:

```
class Canvas:
    def __init__(self,color,pixel):
        self.color = color
        self.pixel = pixel
        
        self.im = np.zeros((pixel,pixel,3))
        self.im[:,:] = color
        
    def show(self):
        plt.imshow(self.im)
        plt.axis("off")
```

This simple class draws a square with color, for example:

```
purple = np.array([0.5, 0.0, 0.5])
C = Canvas(purple, 2001) # 2001 x 2001 pixels
C.show()
```

renders:
[image]

I want to create `add_disk()` function with three argument: `centroid,radius,color`. So that

```
C.add_disk((1001, 1001), 500, white)
C.show()
```

renders: [image]

However, I am not sure how to do it using the math formula:

[image]

I think I can use `np.meshgrid` to color white points, but how do I find those points and display on top of the square?

Comment: Check out if this resolves your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with meshgrid, using the shape of the `self.im`, we first find the coordinates of the `X` and `Y` values in the 2D image. Then, we find all values whose coordinates follows the circle rule (`(X - Ox) ** 2 + (Y - Oy)**2 <= R**2`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Canvas:
    def __init__(self,color,pixel):
        self.color = color
        self.pixel = pixel
        
        self.im = np.zeros((pixel,pixel,3))
        self.im[:,:] = color
        
    def show(self):
        plt.imshow(self.im)
        plt.axis("off")
    
    def add_disk(self, centroid,radius,color):
        x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(self.im.shape[0]), np.arange(self.im.shape[1]))
        circle_pixels = (x - centroid[0]) ** 2 + (y - centroid[1]) ** 2 <= radius ** 2
        self.im[circle_pixels, ...] = color

purple = np.array([0.5, 0.0, 0.5])
C = Canvas(purple, 2001) # 2001 x 2001 pixels
C.show()       

white = np.array([255, 255, 255])
C.add_disk((1001, 1001), 500, white)
C.show()
```

[image]